# jetty-maven-plugin closes websocket with CloseReason[1006,WebSocket Read EOF] on any message send to client

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-jetty-plugin, java-websocket

I've got java server application which uses jetty-maven-plugin in its pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.14.v20161028</version>
            <configuration>
                <stopKey>STOP_LOCAL</stopKey>
                <stopPort>30474</stopPort>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>java.net.preferIPv4Stack</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/myApp</contextPath>
                    <jettyEnvXml>src/main/resources/jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>
                </webAppConfig>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and also

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My server is unable to send any message back to client, if I launch it via eclipse maven build with goal jetty:run.

Websocket is being closed with CloseReason[1006,WebSocket Read EOF] right after I call javax.websocket.Session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(jsonMessage)

(I'm using simple google chrome websocket client for testing)

However if I pack my application to war and launch it under Tomcat 8.5.4 everything works like a charm.

Please, help find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Kaspersky closed ws connection, and didn't close wss :(